# How to order results randomly, but with exceptions?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am creating Quiz and Test system.

In the database, we have a list of questions, and a list of possible answers.

These are all supposed to be returned in random order, so students cannot copy from each others' work.

The one exception is when questions have a possible answer like "All Of The Above", in which case we give it a boolean value, `[AlignBottom]`. If `[AlignBottom]` is 1, **we must force this answer to appear last under a given question, with the rest of the answers still loaded randomly before it.**

This is what I tried first just to see what would happen. Obviously it didn't work:

```
SELECT [AnswerID]
      ,[QuestionID]
      ,[AnswerValue]
      ,[IsCorrect]
      ,[AlignBottom]
  FROM [dbo].[Test-Answers]
  WHERE QuestionID = 4
  ORDER BY AlignBottom ASC, NewID()
```

And I couldn't find this specific sort of solution on SO.

Help?

Comment: Is there sample data to test against?  Also, why the random load before answer where [AlignBottom] = 1?  Lastly, is there grouping to happen, should you remove the questionID where clause?

Comment: This should be done in the presentation layer, not in the db.

Comment: @TinyHaitian I feel like this is a simple enough question to not need sample data. I want to return Answers in a random order, but force certain ones last. There is similar function innate to MySQL that orders nulls this way. There must be a straightforward solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your description, your query should work:

```
ORDER BY AlignBottom ASC, NewID()
```

Comment: This is really bizarre. My issue wasn't with the ASC/DESC syntax, I simply thought you couldn't make it do that. I was getting an undesirable result, sometimes an error, with the example I used in my question and now it's working when I run it on its own...

Comment: This obviously had to be an oversight on my part. I must have had an unseen syntax error somewhere.

Comment: Agree. This solution is better.

Answer (score 1):

Replace ORDER clause with next:

```
Order by case when [AlignBottom] = 1 then -1 else abs(checksum(NewID())) end desc
```

Comment: Beautiful, elegant, charming, graceful, and the answer was great too.

Comment: @TRose . . . Personally, I do not see any elegance or charm to forcing `newid()` into a numeric value.  Two `order by` keys is simpler.